# Is there a built-in ExpectNonNull?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0

In my code, when something is declared as nullable, but I expect it to be non-null at run-time, I can do something like this:

```
someObject.ExpectNonNull().SomeMember
```

The ExpectNonNull is implemented like this:

```
[return: NotNull]
public static T ExpectNonNull<T>(
    [NotNull] this T? arg,
    [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(arg))] string arg_name = ""
)
    where T : class
{
    if (arg is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(
            arg_name,
            $"The argument `{arg_name}` with type {typeof(T).Name} is expected to be non-null, but is null."
        );
    return arg;
}
```

*(There is also a version for value types.)*

Is there anything similar built-into the .NET itself?

Comment: You can use [null-forgiving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) operator. This will eliminate compiler warning, but still raise nullref in the runtime

Comment: Is it what you want ```someObject?.SomeMember```

Comment: @MichaelMao This gives a nullable result. Consider: `string? s = "abc"; var len = s?.Length;`. In this example, the `len` is `int?`.

Comment: @Neistow Yup, that's fine is I'm accessing the member immediately. However, I might just want to ensure that the object is non-null before passing it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

As of .NET 6, you can use [`ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception.throwifnull?view=net-7.0) for at least *some* of what you're after:

```cs
public void SomeMethod(string text)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(text);
    // Use text here, confident that it's not null
}
```

It doesn't allow the kind of fluent approach you're using, but in some cases it's all you need.